# 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have this simple code in my project:

File `api.js`:

```
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

let apiUrl = process.env.API_URL;

const axiosApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl
})

axiosApi.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    config.headers['X-Client'] = 'Crawl'   
    return config
})

const get = async (url) => {
    return await
        axiosApi
            .get(url,{
                crossDomain: true
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response?.data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw error
            })
}

const post = async (url, data) => {
    return await axiosApi
        .post(url, Array.isArray(data) ? [...data] : { ...data })
        .then(response => response?.data)
        .catch(error => {
           console.log("error")
        })
}

module.exports = { get, post }
```

File `app.js`:

```
const api = require('./Api')

api.get('/users').then(data => console.log(data))
```

If I use `curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` I see the data.

But when I use `node app.js` I get this `ERR_BAD_REQUEST`:

> 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

I read many similar questions, but they are all about Nginx or Apache or other web servers. I'm connecting to a public API, thus it's not related to that.

What could be wrong? What should I do?

Edit:
I noticed that this problem occurs when set proxy or use v2ray

But I don't understand why `node.js` causes this problem but it works properly with `curl`

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.API_URL`?  (Don't guess. Log it while running your app).

Comment: "*But I don't understand why node.js causes this problem but it works properly with curl*" are you sure curl is using that proxy?

Comment: @derpirscher

I don't know how to find out about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simplifying the code and adding some debugging ?

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

async function getUsers() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
getUsers()
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-9xhiqf?file=index.js